# Why are you forced to have an empty method to use a method with input parameters?

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller

I'm calling an apex controller class method from my visual force page using an actionFunction like so:

```
<apex:form >
        <apex:actionFunction name="FunctionName" action="{!MyControllerFunction}">
            <apex:param name="Src" value="MySrc"/>
        </apex:actionfunction>
 </apex:form>
```

Initially, this controller method had no input parameters, but I had to add one during development. When I tried to do so on the controller class, I was notified that other pages were using the previous method with no parameters, and to change those first.

```
public PageReference MyControllerFunction(String Src)
{
    //Some stuff
    return pr;    
}
```

Sure, so I added the parameter as shown above in my actionFunction definition. But, when I try to save this, I'm given yet another error:

```
Error: Unknown method 'MyController.MyControllerFunction()' 
Quick Fix   Create Apex method 'MyController.MyControllerFunction'
```

Does this mean I'll have to go back and create a blank method of:

```
public PageReference MyControllerFunction()
    {
        //Some stuff
        return pr;    
    }
```

whenever I need to add parameters to any function? Or am I missing something here?

---

**Update**:

```
<apex:form >
        <apex:actionFunction name="GetPageRef" action="{!MyControllerFunction}">
            <apex:param name="Src" value="MySrc" assignTo="{!SrcVal}"/>
        </apex:actionfunction>
    </apex:form>
```

Apex:

```
public transient String SrcVal{ get; set; }
public PageReference MyControllerFunction()
    {
        //Some stuff
        //Use SrcVal
        return pr;    
    }
```

When it tries to use SrcVal in the controller function, it is coming up blank. 
From your updated answer, it appears that in order to use the transient property for my global variable, I need to also apply the rerender attribute on the actionfunction call. I'm having difficulty finding the keywords allowed for this, should it just be "variables" similar to how you are rerendering "messages" in your example?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Action Functions and RemoteAction functions aren't the same thing. I don't see the relationship here.

Comment: @sfdcfox Do you not agree that your own answer to that question is quite similar to what you posted here?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I found that post useful, but did not find the solution there appealing. I don't want to have to change all of my action functions and controller methods to remote actions when this happens. sfdcfox's solution is much more flexible and doesn't require a complete restructuring.

Comment: I don't understand why so much focus on remoting, that was one answer proposed, but there are other answers that already cover how to use `actionFunction` to do what you need.

Comment: Lol. You're right. My answer there is a duplicate of this one. I suppose it being at the bottom, people might not realize it's there (I certainly didn't).

Comment: @AdrianLarson I see an answer there similar to what sfdcfox posted here, but I wouldn't call it a duplicate. He's using the page parameters and rerender, what I'm asking and what was answered here seems far simpler. Either way, thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 6):

I find it far simpler to use the assignTo attribute to set my parameters:

```
public class MyController {
    public transient String src { get; set; }
    public PageReference MyControllerFunction() {
        // src will be set here
        return pr;
    }
}
```

Then, you can change your action function to:

```
<apex:form >
    <apex:actionFunction name="FunctionName" action="{!MyControllerFunction}">
        <apex:param name="Src" value="MySrc" assignTo="{!src}" />
    </apex:actionfunction>
</apex:form>
```

You can't remove a function from a class until all of the pages/components that use it no longer reference it. That means more edits in the long run. Using transient variables and assigning values to it allows you to preserve a zero-parameter function, and your transient variables get bound only to the pages/components that need it.

---

Functional Example:

### Controller

```
public class Echo {
    public String value { get; set; }
    public void echoValue() {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Value sent was: '+value));
    }
}
```

### Page

```
<apex:page controller="Echo">
    <apex:form>
        <script>
        function handle(event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                echo(event.target.value);
            }
        }
        </script>
        <p>
            Type something here, then press Enter to see it echoed back.
        </p>
        <input type="text" onkeypress="handle(event)" />
        <apex:actionStatus id="status" startText="Working..." />
        <apex:actionFunction name="echo" action="{!echoValue}" reRender="messages" status="status">
            <apex:param name="value" value="" assignTo="{!value}" />
        </apex:actionFunction>
        <apex:pageMessages id="messages" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Can you explain your use of transient here and why it's necessary? Also is there another attribute I need to set, possibly rerender? The value isn't updating on MyController.

Comment: @JWiley It's not "necessary", but usually desirable. The [transient](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_transient.htm) keyword means that the variable won't be serialized to the view state. This means the page won't remember the value between transactions, which is usually desirable for a function parameter. However, you might also decide to not use transient, which would allow the actionFunction to set a value that could be used in other functions later. For example, you might use it to set a sort field on a table.

Comment: @JWiley You actually do need to specify a reRender attribute (I usually do this in practice anyways, so I didn't think about it). I'll include a functional example for you in a moment.

Comment: thank you! I do think I should be using the transient property from what you've explained so far. I updated my question with my use of it, but I'm having an issue locating any Salesforce documentation on what's allowed for the rerender property. Could you shed some light there?

Comment: @JWiley You can see that in any of the documentation, for example, [apex:actionFunction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm):

> The ID of one or more components that are redrawn when the result of the action method returns to the client. This value can be a single ID, a comma-separated list of IDs, or a merge field expression for a list or collection of IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Methods which are called from VF are required to take no parameters. To get the result you're looking for, the standard practice is to use apex:params, but you're missing a small detail. [Here's a blog post](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2011/07/passing-parameters-to-apex-method-from.html) from Bob Buzzard which explains in some detail, but basically you need to declare some transient class variables and bind them to the `assignTo` attribute of the apex:param